# How to map Linux hard drive identifiers like "sd 3:0:0:0:" to ones like "ata8:"?

Tags: linux, kernel, linux-kernel, hard-disk, hardware

In my kernel log, I can see entries like:

> [    0.765510] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] 3907029168 512-byte logical blocks: (2.00 TB/1.81 TiB)

and when something fails, it's usually something like:

> [ 6007.433977] ata8.00: revalidation failed (errno=-5)

How can I translate the sd:X:X:X:X to ataX:00 so I could figure out which drive is failing?

Comment: Have you tried browsing `/sys/class/block`?

Comment: @Nasha: I tried, but I hadn't seen this mapping there.

Answer (score 0):

To map from kernel device name to ata device name (many to one):

```
readlink /sys/class/block/sda | tr / \\012 | grep '^ata'
```

To map from ata device name to kernel device name (one to many):

```
ls -l /sys/class/ata_port/ata1/device/host*/target*/*/block
```

Comment: ***readlink /sys/class/block/sda | tr / \\012 | grep '^ata'*** I get no results for disks that are on LSI SAS controllers and not on the chipset ports.